# HTML and CSS: How to lay out a div tag with width:100% and left:300px

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem setting the style of a div tag. I wanted to have a div tag starting at left:300px and span across till the end of the browser screen. But if I put width:100%, the div tag will go outside of the browser screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery

```
$('.elementClass').width($(window).width()-300);
```

Comment: You'll have to wrap this in a listener for window.onresize or else it'll break when the user resizes their browser window.

Comment: maybe jquery is the best way as long as i do the same on resize as well

Comment: It's kind of a brute force way to do it, but it's pretty consistent

Comment: True.. I may use this way... If I use CSS i have to consider more where other browser will act the same

Comment: No reason to use JavaScript for something you can easily achieve in CSS alone.

Answer (score 2):

Just use right.

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  right: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v2qq0gyp/1/

You can also do this for top and bottom, which results in a full page div:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

With position relative:

```css
div {
    position: relative;    
    left: 30%;
    right: 0;    
    margin-right: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In erat urna, interdum non velit id, fringilla tempus lectus. Integer fermentum est in nisi lobortis aliquet. Sed rutrum purus purus, non fermentum nulla volutpat id. In lacus lacus, condimentum ut sollicitudin id, finibus et sem. Nulla magna elit, sagittis vitae tortor eu, tempor placerat elit. Fusce fringilla quam in erat commodo, eget vehicula tellus eleifend. Donec vitae nisi urna.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In erat urna, interdum non velit id, fringilla tempus lectus. Integer fermentum est in nisi lobortis aliquet. Sed rutrum purus purus, non fermentum nulla volutpat id. In lacus lacus, condimentum ut sollicitudin id, finibus et sem. Nulla magna elit, sagittis vitae tortor eu, tempor placerat elit. Fusce fringilla quam in erat commodo, eget vehicula tellus eleifend. Donec vitae nisi urna.
</div>
```

Comment: Note: This will potentially throw of the layout of the rest of the page though

Comment: testing this code the layout doesnt start 300px to the left, am I missing something?

Comment: @crazymatt Possibly. Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: This is not scrollable, absolute elements are out of flow. Make it relative and I'll give you a thumbs up, but that has to work a bit differently.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `calc` on the width.

Example:

```
div {
 position: absolute;
 left: 300px;
 width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

It is not available in all browsers according to comment... [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/k69qwvgw/) a fiddle nevertheless.

Comment: @SethMcClaine dam you! lol just kidding. thank you for pointing that out, wasn't aware of that

Comment: I really like that solution, didn't know that was available (+1)

Comment: It actually is pretty supported and my personal favorite method. Because it is pure CSS it is the smoothest and fastest solution. http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 1):

Lots of overdone solutions here.

A `div` is a block element, which naturally expands to it's parents full horizontal width. That means that you only need to push it a bit from the left as the minimal solution and depending on the containing element, it will work out of the box. Add a class to the `div` to get some best practice going on and use:

```
.class {
  width: auto; // is default
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use left as %

```
left: 30%;
width: 70%;
```

Comment: Remove the width, div will automaticall expand to the remaining area because it's a block element.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you could solve by adding 'padding-left' or 'margin-left', instead of 'left'. And don't specify 'width: 100%'.

Comment: This  would only work if the content of the div is larger than the remaining space.

Comment: @SethMcClaine elaborate on your comment. 
div by default has 'dispaly: block', which gets the 'width' of its parent minus padding-left/right, margin-left/right and border-left/right.

Comment: @SethMcClaine in first example - actually works! the block has 'moved' to right by 50px. The fact that it makes scroll to appear, it's because of a too long word. And this is not related to this case.

In the second case, yes, you are right. But this are some specific examples. But when you say a 'div', without specifying any style code, you assume it has default style (display: block).

I believe my answer doesn't   deserve '-1' point, which would mean it's not useful. It is useful.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it should works correctly :)

**Code:**

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div> Content </div>
```

Comment: `device-width`doesn't exist as a value of `width`, automatic default is okay, so you can just delete the `width` declaration because `div` is a `display: block` element and will expand naturally to fill the horizontal screenspace..